How to exclude number in MongoDB filter $gte and $lte
I have a MongoDB document with number field:
[
  {
    _id: 1,
    number: 10
  },
  {
    _id: 2,
    number: 11
  },
  {
    _id: 3,
    number: 12
  }
]

And I'm using MongoDB filter $gte and $lte it looks like this:
db.collection.aggregate([{$match: {number: {$gte: 10, $lte: 100}}]

And I want to know is there the way to exclude some numbers? For example I have 100 documents with number from 10 to 100, and I do not want to get number 55 but I still need to use $gte and $lte. How can I do that?
And now I can split my gte and lte numbers and exclude 1 number, but what should I do if I need to exclude 2 or more numbers?

first exclude the docs with the unwanted and then do the compariosn

https://mongoplayground.net/p/PGdwhPqKOSt  you can use $ne for just 1 number https://mongoplayground.net/p/q3NxBsUTBoD

Oh, damn, thanks i will try it

And $nin for more than one

As @cmgchess said in the comment section, you are able to exclude number with $ne and $nin.

$ne: https://mongoplayground.net/p/q3NxBsUTBoD
$nin: https://mongoplayground.net/p/PGdwhPqKOSt

Database:
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "number": 10
  },
  {
    "_id": 2,
    "number": 11
  },
  {
    "_id": 3,
    "number": 12
  },
  {
    "_id": 4,
    "number": 55
  },
  {
    "_id": 5,
    "number": 13
  },
  {
    "_id": 6,
    "number": 56
  },
  {
    "_id": 7,
    "number": 4
  },
  {
    "_id": 8,
    "number": 156
  }
]

$ne query:
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      number: {
        $ne: 55,
        $gte: 10,
        $lte: 100
      }
    }
  }
])

$nin query:
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      number: {
        $nin: [
          55,
          56
        ],
        $gte: 10,
        $lte: 100
      }
    }
  }
])


i think it is better to include the query in answer too. what if the link breaks who knows
